# How to recover from failed kernel or rootfs?

Tags: kernel, embedded-linux, bootloader, reboot, u-boot

I have the ability to boot into several partitions from u-boot: currently running kernel/rootfs, last known good kernel/rootfs, and factory reset kernel/rootfs.

If a kernel/rootfs overwrites part of itself and then continuously resets, should it be able to recover?  I feel like hard-coding fallbacks as a script in the bootcmd environment variable is a bit of a hack.  Is there a common approach to this?

Within the bootcmd variable, nesting a script along the lines of:

```
setenv bootargs "root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rdinit=/bin/kinit rw single"
setenv bootcmd_mmc "ext2load mmc 0:1 0x40000000 my_kernel.itb && bootm"
run bootcmd_mmc

setenv bootargs "root=/dev/mmcblk0p4 rdinit=/bin/kinit rw single"
setenv bootcmd_mmc "ext2load mmc 0:3 0x40000000 my_kernel.itb && bootm"
run bootcmd_mmc

setenv bootargs "root=/dev/mmcblk0p6 rdinit=/bin/kinit rw single"
setenv bootcmd_mmc "ext2load mmc 0:5 0x40000000 my_kernel.itb && bootm"
run bootcmd_mmc
```

Comment: If the **bootm** command actually jumps to the kernel start address (e.g. the *"Starting linux kernel ..."* message), there is no return back to U-Boot (other than a restart).  If the kernel does an oops or panic, the processor can then be halted or reset.  There are no clean *"recover"* possibilities.  One method of restarting from a failed boot is to have a watchdog timer.

Comment: @sawdust, thank you. I didn't release execution would not continue from the middle of u-boot on an oops or panic.  I have a watchdog in the firmware, but was trying to guard against firmware ruining itself and then continuously booting back into its ruined self.

Comment: If you want to interfere with a cycle of Linux boot failures, then you'll have to program the U-Boot environment to select a different kernel image on each start.  When the kernel does successfully boot, the kernel needs to modify U-Boot's environment to inhibit this image re-selection.

Answer (score 0):

There can be various options based on the type of requirement. One of them can be based on disabling the autoboot and taking control. Incase if autoload(autoboot) option is enabled, you may need to disable it. Check the bootdelay parameter. If this is set to -1, the autoboot shall get disabled there by giving you control to change as per your wish.

If you may need to try different configuration via script - the easy way can be modification of the bootcmd variable in your u-boot environment such that it can try to boot by different configurations that are used/applicable for your board by changing the u-boot script for booting.

However, bootm can be really helpful in case of scenario where booting fails due to corrupt image. The below command allows loading of image via tftp server if booting of either the first image or second image fails or if both image files are absent.

`bootm $imageone_addr || bootm $imagetwo_addr || tftpboot $addr $filename && bootm`

Also, an another approach can be loading an alternate image from a set of latest images in every reboot so that the stable version remains without rebooting.